# An elegant way to save versions of code (Xcode)?

Tags: c++, xcode, version-control

I've been searching online for a way to save multiple versions of code with Xcode.  For instance, I just built a program, but I want to add a bunch of changes to it, but don't want to ruin the original.  I could easily just duplicate my .cpp file and continue on, which is what I have been doing, but I just wanted to know if there were any elegant, built in mechanisms for this?  I looked into "source control," but from what I can tell, I have to use an online database, which I would prefer to avoid.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you don't have to use an online database, most (I think any) version control systems are able to use a local repository.

Comment: Look into SVN. TortoiseSVN/GitHub.

Comment: I've been trying to use source control in Xcode without an online database and Im unable to find a way to revert back to older versions.

Comment: Have a look at Git. I believe Xcode has a built in interface for it.

Comment: As @Viggo Lundén' suggested, use git and git branches, supported by XCode or use some external tool

Comment: Git is built in, and there are menu commands for the operations you need. There should be an introduction in XCode's built-in help. (You don't need github or anything else online to use git.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Git` is probably the best solution to the problem, it's built into `XCode` and doesn't have a requirement on an external server but can also be extended out to that if you ever choose to. There's a very good tutorial on getting started with it on [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7).